# Java web service deployed in Glassfish accessible over http and https

Tags: java, web-services, https, glassfish, jax-ws

I'm trying to create a Web Service using JAX-WS and Glassfish 2.1 that is listening to 2 enpoints, one over *http* and the other over *https*. First I have created the web service with the default settings (this means over *http*) and it worked fine. After that I have modified it to accept connections over *https* and this is working also but the initial case stopped working. Can anybody please tell me how to solve this issue? I know it is possible, but I couldn't find the way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: can you access both of your wsdl on both of your port  ?

Comment: No, right now I can access the wsdl just on https(this is port 8181 in my Glassfish).

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've been able to do this is via Apache's proxy pass.  I found this relatively easy to set up too.

Using CentOS, I yum installed apache (which comes with mod_proxy) and mod_ssl.

In the http.conf file, I had the following configuration:

```
Listen 8080
ProxyRequests On
SSLProxyEngine on

AllowCONNECT 8181

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Deny from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / https://radish:8181/
ProxyPassReverse / https://radish:8181/
```

Using this configuration you obviously have to disable the 8080 listener in glassfish.

In the end, I used ProxyPass to forward both ports 80 and 443 from Apache to glassfish port 8181.